# how Marshal.FreeHGlobal() works?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, dll, memory-management

I have a C# based UI which uses C++ based DLL. My requirement was to pass a big chunk of memory from C# to DLL. DLL will write into this memory buffer and pass it back to C#. I have used IntPtr & global memory functions to do this. Everything works fine.

The question is, How to verify if the Marshal.FreeHGlobal() has cleaned the memory? I am using big chunk of memory, usually in terms of MBs. So I want to make sure that the memory is cleaned instantly.

Comment: Your use of "cleaned" suggests you're concerned with security, but I think you really want to know whether the memory has been freed. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, at present I am more concerned about freeing memory.

Comment: The docs say that AllocHGlobal() and FreeHGlobal() are just wrappers around the Win32 LocalAlloc() and LocalFree() functions.  As long as you are using the same allocator on both ends you should be ok.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to check, nor is it at all easy to do so.  The wrapper already bombs if the native Window call fails, good enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you pass a valid handle to `Marshal.FreeHGlobal`, it *will* be freed.  But since the method doesn't return a value, you can't say for sure whether it was cleaned up.

If you have some doubt as to whether you're passing the right thing to `FreeHGlobal`, then I suggest that your code probably isn't as clean as it should be.  But if you really want to make sure, then you could call the `LocalFree` Windows API function, passing it the handle that you would have passed to `FreeHGlobal`:

```
[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError=true)]
static extern IntPtr LocalFree(IntPtr mem);

// Now, to free a block of memory allocated with Marshal.AllocHGlobal
IntPtr rslt = LocalFree(memPtr);
if (rslt == IntPtr.Zero)
{
    // success!
}
else
{
    int err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    // do something with the error.
}
```

I would suggest, however, that if you do this, that you call `LocalAlloc` to allocate the memory rather than calling `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`, as it's possible (although probably unlikely) that future versions of .NET could use something other than `LocalAlloc` to allocate unmanaged memory.  If that happened, then your code that depends on `LocalFree` would break.

Comment: `Marshal.FreeHGlobal` contractually calls `LocalFree`
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.freehglobal(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can probably also allocate the array in managed memory, and then create a `GCHandle` to allow it to be accessed from unmanaged memory.

For example, here I call [`PowerReadACValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372734(v=vs.85).aspx); the Win32 API function takes in an `LPBYTE` buffer (which equates to `BYTE*`).

First I call it with a "null pointer" (IntPtr.Zero), so that it will tell me what size buffer I need (this gets output into bufferSize).  Then I allocate the buffer, and pass in the pointer via `GCHandle`'s `AddrOfPinnedObject`.

```
uint type;
uint bufferSize = 0;

if (SafeNativeMethods.PowerReadACValue(IntPtr.Zero, this.m_planHandle, ref subGroupOfPowerSettingsGuid, ref powerSettingGuid, out type, IntPtr.Zero, ref bufferSize) != 0)
{
    throw new Win32Exception();
}

byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
GCHandle bufferPointer = default(GCHandle);
try
{
    bufferPointer = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    if (SafeNativeMethods.PowerReadACValue(IntPtr.Zero, this.m_planHandle, ref subGroupOfPowerSettingsGuid, ref powerSettingGuid, out type, bufferPointer.AddrOfPinnedObject(), ref bufferSize) != 0)
        throw new Win32Exception();
}
finally
{
    if (bufferPointer.IsAllocated)
        bufferPointer.Free();
}
```

Alternatively, I could have allocated the buffer with `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`, which also returns me an `IntPtr`, and then afterwards free it with `Marshal.FreeGlobal`, but in this case I need to use the data in the array from managed code.  If I were simply going to pass the array pointer to another unmanaged function without ever touching it from managed code, this would be a better way to go (while the GCHandle is active, the memory is locked into place in memory which affects the garbage collector).