# Free memory of IntPtr

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio

I am passing an `IntPtr` to a function [`SendMessageTimeout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644952.aspx) as below. 
 `SendMessageTimeout` belongs to user32.dll.

I dont know how this DLL allcoates memory to the `IntPtr` passed as reference, i.e `result`.

How to release memory of `IntPtr` passed to this function?

```
[DllImport("user32")]
public static extern int SendMessageTimeout(
    int hwnd, int msg, int wparam, int lparam, 
    int fuFlags, int uTimeout, IntPtr lpdwResult);       

if (handle > 0 && GetWindowText(handle, Buff, nChars) > 0)
{
    this.log("GetForegroundWindow : " +Buff.ToString());
    foreach (string str in this.titleList)
    {
        if (Buff.ToString().ToLower().Contains(str.ToLower()))
        {
            IntPtr result = IntPtr.Zero;
            if (SendMessageTimeout(handle, 0x0010, 0, 0, 0x0002, 2000, result) != 0) 
                DestroyWindow(handle);

            killed = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the documentation states that the parameter is optional, why not simply omit it? (i.e. pass `IntPtr.Zero`).

Comment: Thanks.Yeah i think passing IntPtr.Zero makes sense for me. Btw if I have to use this param ,is there any proper way to release the pointer. I coundn't find any proper documentation for user32.dll functions

Comment: Me, neither. After googling, I have no real clue about whether I as the caller am responsible for freeing the memory, or if I can rely on "the system" taking care of freeing this memory.

Comment: The pointer in question is used to store the result of the message processing.  Whether that's a pointer to memory that needs to be freed, and if so, how to free it, *depends upon the message*.  You need to look up the documentation for the specific message you're sending.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Marshal.FreeHGlobal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.freehglobal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) once you finish with it.

You can use FreeHGlobal to free any memory from the global heap allocated by AllocHGlobal, ReAllocHGlobal, or any equivalent unmanaged API method.

```
 Marshal.FreeHGlobal(lpdwResult);
```

Comment: Are you sure about that? I do find no evidence in [the documentation of `SendMessageTimeout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644952.aspx) about how/whether to free the memory at all.

Comment: Probably this answers your doubt ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949084/how-marshal-freehglobal-works

Comment: Sorry, no. Looking at [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19737234/107625), he also does _not_ free the memory of the returned `IntPtr`. In my opinion, you cannot blindly call `FreeHGlobal` on an `IntPtr` without knowing the documentation of the called function.

Comment: @UweKeim: I think you are correct. Probably passing IntPtr.Zero makes sense if he doesn't need to know the out value.